# How to return an unmodifiable view of a Java Trove collection?

Tags: java, collections, trove4j

I'd like to put unmodifiable wrappers around some of the Trove collections: I've checked the Trove documentation and I cannot seem to find an easy way to do it (I may have overlooked something obvious).

So as of now every time I need such an unmodifiable wrapper I'm extending the Trove collection (for example *TIntLongHashMap*) and delegating all the read-only calls to the Trove wrapped subject and throwing an *UnsupportedOperationException* in every method that tries to modify the collection.

Is there an easier way?

**Note:** this question is not about the default Java collections and, in this case, I'm not interested at all neither in the default Java collections nor in other Java collections: this question is specifically about Trove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this with the Trove API, only with the decorators.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer was correct at the time, but for anyone looking to do the same, Trove 3 now supports this via the `TCollections` class.

E.g.

```
TIntLongMap myMap = new TIntLongHashMap();
TIntLongMap myUnmodifiableMap = TCollections.unmodifiableMap(myMap);

myUnmodifiableMap.put(1, 2L); // throws UnsupportedOperationException
```